# Why NetLogo add + 1 twice - when it is not expected?

Tags: git, debugging, netlogo

My question should be quite delicate but related to this one: [NetLogo: avoid to have too many beetles on one patch in one time step?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32891984/netlogo-avoid-to-have-too-many-beetles-on-one-patch-in-one-time-step). The last example work but I have a problem to extend my model.

**The state of my turtles and patches depend mostly of the number and state of the turtles per patch. The thresholds values are set by nmin and nmax per patch.**

**Red** turtle is able to move. When it runs of energy, it infest patch (and change color to **orange**). Once on this patch is enough of "staying = **orange**" turtles = nmin, all **orange** turtles turn to **magenta** and become infesting. The patch still can receive more turtles (maximum number is nmax), but all these turtles turn imidiately to "**magenta**", with no need to become "**orange**". Once the nmax for patch is reached, patch becomes "**brown**" and non attractive for another turtles.

My problem is that I can't set in the right way the `ninf` (how many "infesting = **magenta**") turtles are actually on the patch. I tried different combination of

```
set ninf (ninf + 1)
set ninf (count turtles-here with [status = "infesting"])
```

but it seems that once all turtles become "**magenta**" from "**orange**", my final ninf is amlified by 1 twice not just once. Thus my real number of **magenta** (infesting) turtles per patch is 2, but in patch variable `ninf` it is 3.

I can't use just `ninf (count turtles with..)` because my turtles can die before whole patch is occupied by number nmax. Thus I want patch to "remember" how many `ninf` turtles was there during the simulation run.

Sorry for maybe confusing question but I really don't understand how to extend my working example to working model...

I really appreciate every suggestion, thank you !

```
to turtles_infest

  if ([infestlev] of patch-here = 0 and count turtles-here with [status = "staying"] < [nmin] of patch-here) or
     ([infestlev] of patch-here = 1 and count turtles-here with [status = "infesting"] < [nmax] of patch-here) [
       let available? TRUE

       ifelse available? 
         [ if [infestlev] of patch-here = 0 [
              set color orange
              set status "staying"
              set nstay count turtles-here with [status = "staying"]
              ;set secattract ((0.1 * nstay)  + ninf)    
              ask patch-here [
                infest.patch
              ]
             ] 
          if [infestlev] of patch-here = 1 [
              set color magenta
              set status "infesting"
              set staytime 0
              set time_infest ticks
              set ninf count turtles with [status = "infesting"]
              set secattract ((0.1 * nstay)  + ninf)    
              set totalattract (primattract + secattract)
              kill.patch
              ]
          ]
         [ fd 1 ]
  ]
end

; ---------------------------------------------------------------------
;                          Patch infestation (nstay = nmin)
; ---------------------------------------------------------------------


to infest.patch

  if nstay = nmin [
    set pcolor pink    
    set infestlev 1
    set tree_infestat_time ticks
    set secattract ((0.1 * nstay)  + ninf)    
    set totalattract (primattract + secattract)
    ask turtles-here with [color = orange] [
      set color magenta
      set status "infesting"
      set staytime 0
      set time_infest ticks ]
    set ninf count turtles-here with [status = "infesting"]
  ]
end

; ---------------------------------------------------------------------
;                          Patch dead (ninf = nmax)
; ---------------------------------------------------------------------


to kill.patch  ; just kill the tree, but not put  it as "reproduced? TRUE" because beetles need to reproduce, just the tree should not be attractive for the betles

  if ninf = nmax [
    set pcolor brown
    set infestlev 2
    set time_dead_by_beetle ticks
    set primattract 0
    set secattract 0
    set totalattract 0
  ]
end
```

Comment: This problem is not be a syntax error, it is likely a logic error. The statement `set ninf (count turtles-here with [status = "infesting"])` that you have already tried is correct. If it isn't giving you the right answer, it is because you have accidentally left `set ninf (ninf + 1)` somewhere in your code or a similar problem. I suggest you do a search through your code for the phrase `set ninf` and then do a `show ninf` statement after every set. You may need to run the code slowly to see where it changes unexpectedly.

Comment: Hi @JenB, I'll try it

Comment: Following your suggestion I have realised my error and here is the corrected code. Thank you again !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Corrected code:

```
to turtles_infest

  if ([infestlev] of patch-here = 0 and count turtles-here with [status = "staying"] < [nmin] of patch-here) or
     ([infestlev] of patch-here = 1 and count turtles-here with [status = "infesting"] < [nmax] of patch-here) [
       let available? TRUE
   ifelse available? 
     [ if [infestlev] of patch-here = 0 [
          set color orange
          set status "staying"
          set nstay count turtles-here with [status = "staying"]
          set ninf 0
          show ninf
          ;set secattract ((0.1 * nstay)  + ninf)    
          ask patch-here [
            infest.patch
          ]
         ] 
      if [infestlev] of patch-here = 1 [
          set color magenta
          set status "infesting"
          set staytime 0
          set time_infest ticks
          set ninf count turtles with [status = "infesting"]  ; update ninf only once per tick
          show ninf
          set secattract ((0.1 * nstay)  + ninf)    
          set totalattract (primattract + secattract)
          kill.patch
          ]
      ]
     [ fd 1 ]
  ]
end

; ---------------------------------------------------------------------
;                          Patch infestation (nstay = nmin)
; ---------------------------------------------------------------------


to infest.patch

  if nstay = nmin [
    set pcolor pink    
    set infestlev 1
    set tree_infestat_time ticks
    set secattract ((0.1 * nstay)  + ninf)    
    set totalattract (primattract + secattract)
    ask turtles-here with [color = orange] [
      set color magenta
      set status "infesting"
      set staytime 0
      set time_infest ticks ]
  ;  set ninf count turtles-here with [status = "infesting"] - delete this one
  ;  show ninf 
  ]
end

; ---------------------------------------------------------------------
;                          Patch dead (ninf = nmax)
; ---------------------------------------------------------------------


to kill.patch  ; just kill the tree, but not put  it as "reproduced? TRUE" because beetles need to reproduce, just the tree should not be attractive for the betles

  if ninf = nmax [
    set pcolor brown
    set infestlev 2
    set time_dead_by_beetle ticks
    set primattract 0
    set secattract 0
    set totalattract 0
  ]
end
```